# Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 2

Tags: flask, terminal, development-environment, web-development-server, python-venv

[image: Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 2]

I have uninstalled and reinstalled python-dotenv still i get same error.
Could anyone sort this?

Comment: It would have been so nice if the python-dotenv error message had mentioned which file it didn't like.  In my case it says `line 7`, but my `.env` file only has 3 lines.

Answer (score 28):

Make sure your .env file only contains data in the following format:

```
MY_ENV_VAR = value
```

Anything other than this and you will get `NoneType` if you are trying to retrieve them.

When you are trying to retrieve these you can do the following:

```
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv

env_path = Path('.', '.env')
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)

my_env_var = os.getenv('MY_ENV_VAR')
```

The `env_path` is simply the path to your `.env` file. The '.' is the root directory of your app. You can even pass it in the `dotenv_path` argument like '`\path\to\your\.env'` e.g. `load_dotenv(dotenv_path='\path\to\your\.env')`.

EDIT:

If you are adding it in your terminal, make sure there is no whitespace around the `=` sign. For instance:

Linux:

```
$ export MY_ENV_VAR=value
```

Windows:

```
> set MY_ENV_VAR=value
```

Answer (score 11):

For me the problem disappeared when I deleted space after equality sign and removed apostrophes (`'`) and quotation marks (`"`) from my .env file. So instead of this .env:

```
FOO = 'something'
BAR = "something_else"
```

Try changing .env to:

```
FOO=something
BAR=something_else
```

Comment: exactly solved my problem. Removed all quote mark, whitespace, comma

Answer (score 3):

> I'm seeing this too. It happens if the last line in the .env file is empty.
>
> Some quick testing shows that it appeared in 0.10.4; with 0.10.3 no warning is displayed.

https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv/issues/235

This may helps

Answer (score 0):

In my case, that was not the issue, even I had empty lines at the end.
The culprit was a breaking strict rules line copied from a Dockerfile

ENV VAR=value

The python env, and env files are restrictive to just a name identifier with underscores, an equal and all to the left is taken as the value for the identifier.
"ENV " part was breaking that strict rule...

It need to be just
VAR=value

While some time ago, hope this help others

Answer (score 0):

**Not Sure What the exact reason is**. I also had the same problem. If I remember correctly, the problem arised in my case after pasting the `var=value` pair in the `.env` file using vim.

Removing `var=value` with backspace, and manually typing `var=value` (without pasting) workded for me.*

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error when the comment in my .env file started with `;`

My `Visual Studio Code` for some reason comments out the lines with `;` in place of `#` in .env files

So to fix the error I only had to replace from `;` with `#` in my commented lines

Answer (score 0):

Just simply inspect your .env file

- make sure strings are closed if opened
- comment properly
- wrap possible conflicting character values with a string